Partitions of bent vectors
Let $H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$ Let $A^{\otimes N}$ denote the tensor product of the matrix $A$ with itself taken $N$ times. We say that a vector $v$ of length $2^{2n}$ is a bent vector if each entry in $v$ and in $H^{\otimes 2n}v$ is $\pm 1$. There are plenty of examples of bent vectors, but I am wondering if one can typically decompose these bent vectors into a sum of simpler vectors.
We say that a collection of vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_p)\in(\mathbb{R}^{2^{2n}}\setminus\mathbf{0})^p$ is a partition of a bent vector if each entry in $v_j$ and in $H^{\oplus 2n}v_j$ is in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ and where $\|v_1\|^2+\dots+\|v_j\|^2=2^{2n}$ and where $v_1+\dots+v_p$ is a bent vector. Equivalently, a partition of a bent vector is a collection of vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_p)\in(\mathbb{R}^{2^{2n}}\setminus\mathbf{0})^p$ where each entry in $v_j$ is in $\{-1,0,1\}$, and if $v=v_1+\dots+v_p$, then $v$ is a bent vector, and if $S_j=\{s:(v_j)_s\neq 0\}$, then $(S_1,\dots,S_p)$ is a partition of $\{1,\dots,2^{2n}\}.$
What are some examples of partitions of bent vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_p)$ with $p>1$?
